# How do I get the attachments for a SP 2010 list to sort the attachments in alpha order by document name?

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-foundation, attachments, sorting

How do I get the attachments on my SharePoint 2010 List item to sort in alphabetical order by document name?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to get the same but unfortunately SharePoint doesn't seems to be providing such facility while MOSS 2007 do. Here is the workaround that i have found and it worked for me. Please keep in mind this will sort the items only in alphabetical order (regardless of numerical order). Hope [this](http://like2know.blogspot.com/2014/09/sorting-sharepoint-list-item.html) helps someone.

Good Luck :)

Comment: Please add the main points from the link to the answer so that if link goes down the answer is still relevant.

Answer (score 0):

I think this article can help you:

http://fixingsharepoint.blogspot.com.br/2014/09/sorting-sharepoint-list-item.html

Comment: Can you please extract some details from the link.